# celery parameters has correct number of arguments

Tags: python, django, celery

I am using celery 4.0 and was following this site. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#blog-tasks-py

views.py

```
task = test2.delay(document.name, document.id)
```

Tasks.py

```
@shared_task(name="test2")
def test2(param, job_id):
    return 'The test task executed with argument "%s" ' % param
```

However, it throws an exception `TypeError: test2() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. This is funny since i have 2 arguments and it works in the site i shown.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine and the minimal code posted here works fine.  You probably have a messed up import (i.e., test2 defined in multiple places) or a stray .pyc file lying around.

Comment: @2ps I think i forgot to restart celery after modifying my tasks file. I guess this is why it threw the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For folks that stumble upon this in the future;

You probably forgot to restart celery, friend!